# History command for shell command in C. Where to start

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

I'm having trouble starting this code, I really have no idea where to start. I'm trying to understand what to do. Pretty much what I have to do is once i execute the file i should be able to just type in "history" and it should bring up all my history of commands used. How would I code this file to allow me to do that? Any hints or clues would be appreciated!

Comment: `Any hints or clues...` -- Look at `bash` [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/).

Comment: And perhaps use [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library.

Comment: I've looked through the readline library, those all look complex. Is there a simpler way to edit my makefile and just make a history that's able to use the command !(number), !(string) for last string used, and !! for the last command used?

Comment: Using `readline` library is fairly simple; it handles most of it for you.  Doing it yourself will involve handling 70% of what `readline` handles.  If you don't have to reinvent the wheel, don't.

Answer (score 3):

The basics are relatively straight-forward.  You need to design a suitable on-disk format for the history, bearing in mind you probably don't want the file to grow indefinitely large (though that might be OK for a first version).  And you'll need a set of functions to manipulate the file (open, close, write, search).

Each time you read a command (complete command — a pipeline, or a `for` loop, or whatever), you also write to your history mechanism.

Your history mechanism should also allow you to retrieve previous commands, to list them, or to search them by content or by number.

Niceties you should consider include ensuring that the history file is closed when other commands are executed, and ensuring sub-shells don't write to the history (usually).  You need to think about whether you can have multiple shells accessing the same history file; will your history persist across sessions? What happens if you have two terminal windows open at the same time?

The GNU [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library has hooks to make it possible to integrate with a history library.  It also provides a history library.

Comment: Thanks, someone said earlier but it seemed to have been deleted that I could use the .bash_history file? Would that be something to consider or is a better option to make a new file to hold all the history?

Comment: It is a good practice (in my opinion) to store the history in a file, so your latter executes can also see the history.

Comment: The name of the file you use is up to you; understanding the format of the file will be harder (probably) — hmmm, or maybe not...it seems to be one line of text per history command.  That would explain why bash flattens history so rigorously, wrecking my carefully formatted shell code in the process.  It also means it keeps most of the history information in memory while it is running, merely dumping the history to disk when it exits.  Oh well... Korn shell history uses null-terminated strings and preserves newlines in single commands.